# How to multiply variable correctly?

Tags: c

Im making a shipping calculator that ask how many pounds your item weighs. If it weighs less than 50 pounds the charge is 6.00. If it weighs 50 pounds but less than 100 pounds the charge is 10.50. The shipping charge also doubles for every 1000 miles. Im having a problem figuring out how to make the calculator double if user inputs over 1000 miles.

```
int main()
{
double weight, distance, charge;

printf("Enter your package weight: \n");
scanf("%lf", &weight);
printf("How far are you sending the package? \n");
scanf("%1lf", &distance);

if(weight <= 50)
    charge = 6;
else
    if(weight <= 100)
        charge = 10.50;

printf("Shipping charge: %.2lf\n", charge);

}
```

When I run the program I dont get the correct shipping charge.

Comment: Always a bug: not testing the return value from scanf(). It should be 1 in each case.

Comment: If you have nested `if else` statements, better use `{}`. For instance your indentation does not match the logical nesting.

Comment: Show where is multiplication operator `*` in your code?

Comment: You don't set a value to `charge` when `weight > 100`. Also, is the `1` in `scanf("%1lf", &distance);` a typo? It should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should printf the charge instead of the weight?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are outputting `weight` in the end and not the `charge`, the one that was actually mutated.

Comment: I got it to work as far as entering the weight and how far they are sending. Which way works the best for multiple by every thousand miles for the shipping charge?